# How do I encrypt EventStore on disc?

Tags: encryption, eventstoredb

For my sins, I'm responsible for databases that store Personally Identifiable Information and possible HIPAA-protected data.

So this data needs to be stored encrypted both in transit and at rest.

We currently use MSSQL Enterprise with TDE.

We are looking at [[Get]EventStore](http://geteventstore.com), which maintains its data as straight files typically <1MB on a file system of its host.  Among our questions are: how do we encrypt it? How do we back it up?  How do we retain encryption even when backed up?

I would like to do the encryption below the application level.  Vormetric and Gazzang seem to offer options for encrypting virtual devices or disc partitions, but neither seems to solve the backup encryption as simply as using a technology like MSSQL's TDE.

We really want to use EventStore.  I'm hoping there's a good solution I have been too thick to appreciate yet.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the folks at GetEventStore: encrypt at the file system level.